# issue while loading image from image Path iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

well am trying this :

```
    if let storedCoverImagePath = UC.coverImagePath{
    let storedCoverImage    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: storedCoverImagePath as String)
        self.coverImage.image = storedCoverImage
        self.backgroundImageView.image = storedCoverImage
}
```

and the value of storedCoverImagePath is :

```
/Users/remy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D29D4F6F-E146-419D-B4B8-B1914F56569F/data/Containers/Data/Application/637675BB-EFA1-A8RT-8B73-A3628/DocumentsCoverImage.jpg
```

its straight forward that am trying to get an image from this `storedCoverImagePath` path.  i double checked the path, image is there  still am not able to set the image using this path,   is there is something that am missing if yes than  tell me please

Comment: Try set breakpoints on each `if` statements and see if the objects were properly initialized. From those code above it's hard to see the whole picture.

Comment: can you try changing to   `if let storedCoverImagePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("imageName", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: UC.coverImagePath) {  
            self.coverImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: storedCoverImagePath)  
        }`

Comment: Have you hardcoded the `storedCoverImagePath` to this value?

Comment: hey @Aamir i tried your code but no luck , don't know whats wrong here

Comment: hey @Bearwithme well it is hardcoded am fetching image on the startup of app and storing it locally and then storing the files path too and then fetching the image from this path

Comment: hey @Zhi-WeiCai i checked it so many times when am fetching image from local path am not succeeding if i do the same thing from my project's assets file or an url i'm able to get  the image

Comment: Using hard-coded path is never a good idea. You never know if it will get blocked by the sandbox. The app won't be able to fetch files outside it's scope (.app dir or any other allowed places) or any where other than the temporary folder.

Comment: hey @Zhi-WeiCai but the folder is created by the app itself and the file is to written by the app itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **path relative to your apps bundle or directory**. If you hardcode the path like you did:

> `/Users/remy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D29D4F6F-E146-419D-B4B8-B1914F56569F/data/Containers/Data/Application/637675BB-EFA1-A8RT-8B73-A3628/DocumentsCoverImage.jpg`

it gets ignored because of the sandboxing. iOS does not allow the app to reference directories external to the sandbox.

#### Possible solutions

One way to get it working is to add the image to the project. Then you can get it using:

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"ImageName")
```

Another way, if the image is saved in documents directory of your app, is to use:

```
let documentsURL  = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(yourImageName)
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path!)
```

Comment: how can i specify my path with "path relative to your apps bundle or directory" ?? any guidance please ?

Comment: I extended my answer with possible solutions. Please check it out.